# Unable to create 3D function using mesh

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

So I have a script which executes coordinate descent algorithm for a quadratic function. I also created a function to make different plots, this is the first part I add. The code executes without any error, but I'm unable to see the surface, I can only see the path of my algorithm descending.

**The function updater:**

```
function [f,delta] = fcalculator (Q, x0, c, p)
 a = size(x0);
 n = a(2);
 f = (x0*Q*x0') - (c * x0') + p ;
 delta = (Q*x0')- c';
endfunction
```

**The main program:**

```
clear all, close all,
fprintf(' 0 = probleme specifique \n 1 = probleme random \n 2 = Tapez votre propre probleme\n')
choix = input ('Choix :  ');
n=0;
if (choix == 0)

  [Q, x0, c, p] = quadfunctiongenerator(n,choix)

  maxiter = input ( 'Nombre de iterations :'); 
  [x, z] = coordinatedescent(Q,c,p,x0,maxiter);
  visualizer(x, z, Q, c, p);

else

  n = input ('Choix des dimensions: n = ');
  [Q, x0, c, p] = quadfunctiongenerator(n,choix);

endif
```

**The module to create the plots:**

```
function [x1, x2, fuf] = visualizer(x, z, Q, c, p)
clf;
% Pour le cas le plus general, apres on fera:
% iters = 1:size(x)(1);
% plot(iters,x(:,1))
if size(x)(2)
  % Afficher les iterees: 
  plot3(x(:,1), x(:,2), z)
  hold on;
  % fcalculator (Q, x0, c, p)

  % Display the function's surface:
  %% Calculate limits:
  x1_low = x(1,1);
  x1_hi  = x(size(x)(1),1) + x1_low;
  x2_low = x(1,2);
  x2_hi  = x(size(x)(1),2) + x2_low;

  % Resolution will be the number of points:
  resolution = 100;
  x1 = (linspace(x1_low, x1_hi, resolution))';
  x2 = (linspace(x2_low, x2_hi, resolution))';
  f = [];

  [xx, yy] = meshgrid (x1, x2);

  for i=1:resolution
    for j=1:resolution
      [_tmp, _] = fcalculator(Q, [x1(i),x2(j)], c, p);
      f(i,j) = _tmp;
    endfor
  endfor 

  _string = sprintf('%d ', size(x1));
  fprintf('Answer: %s\n', _string);

  _string = sprintf('%d ', size(x2));
  fprintf('Answer: %s\n', _string);

  _string = sprintf('%d ', size(f));
  fprintf('Answer: %s\n', _string);

  mesh(x1, x2, f);

endif

endfunction
```

I believe the problem is my call to `mesh()` as I didn't use the variables `xx` and `yy`  created when calling `meshgrid()` but the dimensions of `x1`, `x2` and `f` are the same as those of the variables used to create the famous sombrero plot:

```
tx = ty = linspace (-8, 8, 41)';
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (tx, ty);
r = sqrt (xx .^ 2 + yy .^ 2) + eps;
tz = sin (r) ./ r;
mesh (tx, ty, tz);
```

Am I supposed to create f as an elementwise operation as shown in the sombrero plot example?

Is there any octave function to help me create the surface of the function I am optimizing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The call to `mesh()` was correct. The problem was the definition of the boundaries.

```
  x1_low = x(1,1);
  x1_hi  = x(size(x)(1),1) + x1_low;
  x2_low = x(1,2);
  x2_hi  = x(size(x)(1),2) + x2_low;
```

Yielded `x1_low == x1_hi`. The code was replaced with:

```
 x1_low = min(x(:,1));
 x1_hi  = max(x(:,1));
 x2_low = min(x(:,2));
 x2_hi  = max(x(:,2));
```

Which yielded the desired surface.

Comment: @EBH I will, but I have to wait two days.